# Convert selected numeric dataframe fields to two fields representing a range

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an arbitrary dataframe, `dw`, with numeric and character fields with arbitrary names and in an arbitrary order. (That is, I do not know what the name of the fields are and I do not which fields will be numeric.) I want to create a new dataframe, `dw2`, that includes two numeric fields replacing each numeric field in the original data frame. The column order and the name of the numeric fields replacing the original numeric field names should be similar to the below. Note, that the field `bla` occurs after `fs_hi`. (In the below example the new numeric fields are the original value "-2" and original value "+4" for simplicity.)

```
    dw <- read.table(header=T, text='
 sbj   f1   fs  bla  lt     br    
   A   10    6  bA   50     10    
   B   12    5  bB   70     11    
   C   20    7  bC   20     8     
   D   22    8  bD   22     9     
 ')
dw

  sbj f1 fs bla lt br
1   A 10  6  bA 50 10
2   B 12  5  bB 70 11
3   C 20  7  bC 20  8
4   D 22  8  bD 22  9
```

Desired output, `dw2`

```
  sbj f1_lo f1_hi fs_lo fs_hi bla lt_lo lt_hi br_lo br_hi
1   A     8    14     4    10  bA    48    54     8    14
2   B    10    16     3     9  bB    68    74     9    15
3   C    18    24     5    11  bC    18    24     6    12
4   D    20    26     6    12  bD    20    26     7    13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new dataframe, iterate over all the columns and append copies of the character columns or hi/lo versions of the numeric columns.
Something like:

```
dw2 <- data.frame(row.names = rownames(dw))
for (col in names(dw)) {
  if (is.numeric(dw[[col]])) {
    dw2[paste0(col, '_lo')] <- dw[col] - 2
    dw2[paste0(col, '_hi')] <- dw[col] + 4
  } else {
    dw2[[col]] <- dw[[col]]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question to state that the data frame has "numeric and character fields with arbitrary names and in an arbitrary order."

Comment: Ok, edited my answer as well to work with arbitrary columns types, names and order

Answer (score 1):

You can use tidy functions for this, first to make a nested data.frame for numeric columns with hi and lo, then unnest it while the "hi" / "lo" to original column name:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

dw %>% 
mutate_if(is.numeric,~map(.x,~data.frame(lo=.x-2,hi=.x+4))) %>% 
unnest(cols=c(f1, fs, lt, br),names_sep="_")

# A tibble: 4 x 10
  sbj   f1_lo f1_hi fs_lo fs_hi bla   lt_lo lt_hi br_lo br_hi
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         8    14     4    10 bA       48    54     8    14
2 B        10    16     3     9 bB       68    74     9    15
3 C        18    24     5    11 bC       18    24     6    12
4 D        20    26     6    12 bD       20    26     7    13
```

Comment: thank you. one week (or 2) in the near future i will need to level up to becoming tidyr literate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
#Duplicate for low
dw1 <- dw
dw1[,-c(1,4)] <- apply(dw[,-c(1,4)],2,function(x) x-2)
names(dw1)[-c(1,4)]<-paste0(names(dw1)[-c(1,4)],'_lo')

#Duplicate for high
dw2 <- dw
dw2[,-c(1,4)] <- apply(dw2[,-c(1,4)],2,function(x) x+2)
names(dw2)[-c(1,4)]<-paste0(names(dw2)[-c(1,4)],'_hi')

#Merge
dff <- merge(dw1,dw2,by=c('sbj','bla'))

  sbj bla f1_lo fs_lo lt_lo br_lo f1_hi fs_hi lt_hi br_hi
1   A  bA     8     4    48     8    12     8    52    12
2   B  bB    10     3    68     9    14     7    72    13
3   C  bC    18     5    18     6    22     9    22    10
4   D  bD    20     6    20     7    24    10    24    11
```

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question to state that the data frame has "numeric and character fields with arbitrary names and in an arbitrary order."